# Pip is not working and I can't seem to find how to fix it

Tags: python-3.x

[image]

I haven't been able to find anything useful as far as fixing this and I've only just started learning python.

Answer (score 0):

Try `easy_install pip` this will install pip. 
I would advise installing python using anaconda to avoid such issues

Comment: make sure you start command prompt with administrative privileges.